# React code splitting and server side rendering with System.import or require.ensure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I am investigating code splitting for use in a React application.

I can't seem to find a way to introduce code splitting (and importing) for server side render which carries through to the client side cleanly.

FYI: I know there is a way to do this with React Router, but I think this is a more general issue and not everyone wants to use it. Also, I feel that code splitting is not synonymous with routes necessarily.

Here is a very basic example of a class that will load and render the contents of a split code bundle `SplitComponent`.

If the route that is rendered server side includes this component then `componentWillMount` will ensure that the code is loaded synchronously with `require` before the `render` is called. It checks to see if it's server side so it doesn't do this client side.

Then for the client side, `componentDidMount` will asynchronously load `SplitComponent` with `System.import`.

The result of this is that the server side renders the correct page and the client will display it, but then immediately the `componentDidMount` will cause the client side to load the `SplitComponent`, during which time it will display (however briefly depends on load times) nothing. Finally, `SplitComponent` will load and be rendered. But there is the potential for flicker as it gets removed, then added again. This detracts from the advantages of doing the rendering on the server.

Is there a better way to handle this?

```
import React from 'react';

const canUseDOM = !!(
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.document && window.document.createElement)
);

class Lazy extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      module: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!canUseDOM) {
      const m = require('./SplitComponent');
      this.setState({
        module: m.default
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.module) {
      System.import('./SplitComponent').then(m => {
        this.setState({
          module: m.default
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { module } = this.state;
    console.log('Rendering Lazy', module);
    if (module) {
      return React.createElement(module);
    }

    return null;
  }
}

export default Lazy;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a tricky problem, but I have a solution which seems to work. It's not ideal and I would dearly like to see alternatives.

The basic idea is that one React component can trigger the `import` of another in order to facilitate code splitting. This is reasonably simple, but extending this to support server side rendering added a lot of complexity.

The rules:

1. Import must be synchronous on the server side as there is only a single render.
2. Server side must be able to inform the client side which bundles are required for whatever view is being rendered by the server.
3. Client must then load any bundles that the server informed it about, before React begins rendering.
4. Client then can continue ordinary code-splitting practice from this point onwards. Bundles are loaded asynchronously and once loaded, React rerenders to include them in the rendering.

Here is the `Lazy` class which is responsible for managing code splitting for the `SplitComponent`. It makes use of 2 functions from `split.js`

When `Lazy` is rendered on the server side, `componentWillMount` is run and checks if it is actually the server side. If it is, it causes the loading of the `SplitComponent` synchronously. The module default that is loaded is stored in the state of the `Lazy` component so that it can then immediately be rendered. It also dispatches an action to Redux to register the fact that this bundle is required for the view that is being rendered.

The server side will successfully render the application and the redux store will contain the fact that the bundle containing `./SplitComponent` is required on the client side.

```
//Lazy.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { splitComponent, splitComponentSync } from './split';

const canUseDOM = !!(
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.document && window.document.createElement)
);

class Lazy extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      module: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {

    // On server side only, synchronously load
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    if (!canUseDOM) {

      // Also, register this bundle with the current component state as on
      // the server there is only a single render and thus the redux state
      // available through mapStateToProps is not up-to-date because it was
      // requested before the above dispatch.
      this.setState({
        module: splitComponentSync(dispatch)
      });

    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, modules } = this.props;

    if (!modules.hasOwnProperty('./SplitComponent')) {
      splitComponent(dispatch);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { module } = this.state;
    const { modules } = this.props;

    // On server side, rely on everything being loaded
    if (!canUseDOM && module) {
      return React.createElement(module);

    // On client side, use the redux store
    } else if (modules.hasOwnProperty('./SplitComponent') && modules['./SplitComponent']) {
      return React.createElement(modules['./SplitComponent']);
    }

    return null;
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {

  const modules = state.modules;

  return {
    modules
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Lazy);
```

```
//split.js
export const splitComponent = dispatch => {
  return System.import('./SplitComponent').then((m) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'MODULE_IMPORT',
      moduleName: './SplitComponent',
      module: m.default
    });
  });
};

export const splitComponentSync = dispatch => {
  // This must be an expression or it will cause the System.import or
  // require.ensure to not generate separate bundles
  const NAME = './SplitComponent';
  const m = require(NAME);

  // Reduce into state so that the list of bundles that need to be loaded
  // on the client can be, before the application renders. Set the module
  // to null as this needs to be imported on the client explicitly before
  // it can be used
  dispatch({
    type: 'MODULE_IMPORT',
    moduleName: './SplitComponent',
    module: null
  });

  // Also, register this bundle with the current component state as on
  // the server there is only a single render and thus the redux state
  // available through mapStateToProps is not up-to-date because it was
  // requested before the above dispatch.
  return m.default;
};
```

```
//reducer.js (Excerpt)
export function modules(

    state={}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'MODULE_IMPORT':
          const newState = {
            ...state
          };
          newState[action.moduleName] = action.module;
          return newState;
      }
      return state;
    }
```

The client initialise as per the usual procedure for incorporating the redux store from server rendering.

Once that has happened, it is necessary to ensure that any required bundles are imported before rendering can begin. We examine the redux store `modules` to see what is required. I look them up in a simple if statement here. For each bundle that is required, it is loaded asynchronously, it's module default stored in the redux store and a Promise returned. Once all those promises are resolved, then React will be allowed to render.

```
//configureStore.js (Excerpt)
let ps;
if (initialState && initialState.hasOwnProperty('modules')) {
  ps = Object.keys(initialState.modules).map(m => {
    if (m === './SplitComponent') {
      return splitComponent(store.dispatch);
    }
  });
}

// My configureStore.js returns a Promise and React only renders once it has resolved
return Promise.all(ps).then(() => store);
```

Going forward, whenever `Lazy`+`SplitComponent` are used, no code loading is required because it already exists in the redux store.

In the case when the initial application did not include `Lazy`+`SplitComponent`, then at the point when `Lazy` is rendered by React, `componentDidMount` will fire an asynchronous action to import `./SplitComponent` and register this with redux. Like any redux action, this change in state will cause the `Lazy` component to attempt to rerender and as the `SplitComponent` is now loaded and registered, it can do so.

Comment: I am also facing the flickering issue on my server side rendered page . I am not using redux , can we do the same solution without redux?

Comment: I have not pursued this any further in the time since. I would have a look at the answer of clint.beacock above. I expect that things are evolving rapidly in this space so it'll be worthwhile to do a survey of new approaches to this (such as the one in clint's answer). To explicitly answer your question, yes, I think you could pass through a custom state object where I used redux. As I said in my answer, I didn't like the solution and I would avoid it if I could!

Comment: @John I've managed it by loading esnext import on the browser while the rest of the app is rendered server side: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486954/1951947

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a method that greatly reduces the amount of boilerplate involved in your solution, I'd recommend checking out 'react-async-component' (https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-async-component)

Description from the github page:

> Create Components that resolve asynchronously, with support for server side rendering and code splitting.
>
> This library is an evolution of code-split-component. Unlike code-split-component this library does not require that you use either Webpack or Babel. Instead it provides you a pure Javascript/React API which has been adapted in a manner to make it generically useful for lazy-loaded Components, with support for modern code splitting APIs (e.g import(), System.import, require.ensure).

I was having the same issue (a half-second flicker on the client-side render), and your solution was the only one I had found to address it, but since then I came across this library, and it worked like a charm for me.

It works by storing the state of the component on the `window` object in the server-rendered template, which it uses client-side until the async client-side render is complete.

The documentation is good as well, which is always nice.

After a small amount of boilerplate to wrap your render methods on the server and client side, its as easy as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAsyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';

const AsyncComponent = createAsyncComponent({
  resolve: () => System.import('./components/MyComponent')
});

<AsyncComponent myProp={1} />
```

Give it a try.  I hope it works as well for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in comments, here i show a vanilla solution.

I just use React.lazy/Suspense only when i'm on browser leaving the rest of the app render server side.

[Here you can check my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486954/1951947)